# iOS Search Devices on LAN

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7

I'm trying to figure out how to create a little app which scans the local network and displays list of connected devices, their IP address and mac address but I couldn't find starting point.

I'll be very thankful if anyone can guide me what to read in terms of iOS libs and frameworks.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might be on your own here. I'd take a look at the source code of Lan-Scan, see how it does the ping and tweak it to work as you require it to. It might be worth trying to reverse-engineer some existing apps to see how they work!. I'd be up for collaborating on this, if this is an open source project. Thanks :)